# What is keystore and truststore and how they differ from each other

Tags: security, ssl, keystore, truststore

Can anyone give some idea on what is keystore and truststore , are they both same ? or any difference between them ? which file will be present on client side and which file will be on server side .

Context : general , not specific to any programming language. Is this will change based on programming language ?

Comment: Is this supposed to be general, or specific to some technology? [tag:keystore] is specific to Java for instance. Add more information about what context you encountered those terms in.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the difference is the intended usage, because the physical support can be the same. A PKCS#12 or JKS file can be used for both purposes

- **keystore**: contains keys and certificates used for authentication, encryption or digital signature
- **truststore**: contains third party certificates in which you trust

For example in a SSL/TLS connection the truststore contains the set of accepted CA root certificates, and the keystore the certificate used for client authentication

Answer (score 0):

Without getting overly precise:

- **Truststore**: a file containing the *public keys* of the PKI certificates that you consider trusted.  When you're either getting an SSL connection from another site, or you're making an SSL connection to another site, you compare the public key from the other site's PKI certificate - the other site will send that to you - to the public keys in your truststore.  If the public key that the other site sends you can be verified to be signed by one of the trusted keys in your truststore, you will trust the site that sent you the key.
- **Keystore**: a file containing keys and certificates.  This can be a file that contains the public and private keys of the PKI certificate you use to identify yourself, or it can be the above-described truststore.

Comment: The truststore contains certificates, not just their public keys. The key comparison process you describe is not what actually happens.

Comment: @EJP But the certificates in the truststore do not contain the private key - the only thing they contain is the public key (and the metadata used to identify them...). They're not complete certificates. The answer was meant to be a quick, generic overview targeted to someone who isn't intimately familiar with the details.  For someone who doesn't even know what a truststore is, explaining the key signing and verification process wouldn't add to understanding.  You're welcome to write your own answer.